# Can I use a car jack for a broken bed leg?

Tags: bedroom

I have a steel bed and one of the legs is broken. I think the bed leg would require welding but then I got an idea, why not use one of these jack stands: [2 Piece Pair 3 Ton Heavy Duty Adjustable Jack Stand](https://www.amazon.ae/Piece-Pair-Heavy-Adjustable-Stand/dp/B07MVWTGW6/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=car%20jack&qid=1586011233&sr=8-3&tag=coa_row-20) instead?

My question is, would this jack stand meet the requirements? Or would it cause any issues such as creaking or wobbliness? The base of my bed is around 10.5 inches above the floor. Would the jack stand fit the height of the bed?

Comment: When your significant other sees it, I’ll bet she’ll be offended.

Comment: For now, can you try a stack of books?  If that doesn't hold up, neither will the jack stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weight capacity, no problem.

Staying put, noise from motion, stubbing your toes, limited height adjustability; all probable or definite problems.

Bed frames in perfectly usable shape tend to go for a song at secondhand stores, or end up in the waste stream as they rarely get sold and too many are donated. I suggest you go buy one of them, and then see if you can find a place to take your broken frame as scrap steel rather than trash.

Either that, or have it welded.

Answer (score 1):

You should try J-B Weld. It worked great on a water pump for several years.